# Simple SpriteKit game performance issues - Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cpu-usage, skscene

Apologies in advance as I'm not sure exactly what the right question is.  The problems that I'm ultimately trying to address are:

1) Game gets laggy at times

2) CPU % can get high, as much as 50-60% at times, but is also sometimes relatively low (<20%)

3) Device (iPhone 6s) can get slightly warm

I believe what's driving the lagginess is that I'm constantly creating and removing circles in the SKScene.  It's pretty much unavoidable because the circles are a critical element to the game and I have to constantly change their size and physicsBody properties so there's not much I can do in terms of reusing nodes.  Additionally, I'm moving another node almost constantly.

```
func addCircle() {

    let attributes = getTargetAttributes() //sets size, position, and color of the circle


    let target = /*SKShapeNode()*/SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: attributes.size.width)
    let outerPathRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: attributes.size.width * 2, height: attributes.size.width * 2)

    target.position = attributes.position
    target.fillColor = attributes.color
    target.strokeColor = attributes.stroke
    target.lineWidth = 8 * attributes.size.width / 35
    target.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: attributes.size.width)

    addStandardProperties(node: target, name: "circle", z: 5, contactTest: ContactCategory, category: CircleCategory) //Sets physicsBody properties

    addChild(target)


}
```

The getAttributes() function is not too costly.  It does have a while loop to set the circle position, but it doesn't usually get used when the function is called.  Otherwise, it's simple math.

Some other details:

1) The app runs at a constant 120 fps.  I've tried setting the scene/view lower by adding `view.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60` in GameScene.swift and `gameScene.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60` in GameViewController.  Neither one of these does anything to change the fps.  Normally when I've had performance issues in other apps, the fps dipped, however, that isn't happening here.

2) I’ve tried switching the SKShapeNode initializer to use a path versus circleOfRadius and then resetting the path.  I’ve also tried images, however, because I have to reset the physicsBody, there doesn’t appear to be a performance gain.

3) I tried changing the physicsWorld speed, but this also had little effect.

4) I've also used Instruments to try to identify the issue.  There are big chunks of resources being used by SKRenderer, however, I can't find much information on this.

Comment: SKShapeNodes are inefficient and should be used sparingly.  I would recommend creating 1 circle and just scale it

Answer (score 2):

Creating `SKShapeNodes` are inefficient,  try to use it as few times as you can.  instead, create a template shape,  and convert it to an `SKSpriteNode`.

If you need to change the size,  then use `xScale` and `yScale`, if you need to change the color, then use `color` with `colorBlendFactor` of 1

If you need to have a varying color stroke,  then change the below code to have 2 `SKSpriteNodes`,  1 `SKSpriteNode` that handles only the fill, and 1 `SKSpriteNode` that handles only the stroke.  Have the stroke sprite be a child of the fill sprite with a `zPosition` of `0` and set the stroke color to white.  You can then apply the `color` and `colorBlendFactor` to the child node of the circle to change the color.

```
lazy var circle =
{
   let target = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 1000)
   target.fillColor = .white
   //target.strokeColor = .black //if stroke is anything other than black, you may need to do 2 SKSpriteNodes that layer each other
   target.lineWidth = 8 * 1000 / 35

   let texture = SKView().texture(from:target)
   let spr = SKSpriteNode(texture:texture)
   spr.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 1000)
   addStandardProperties(node: spr, name: "circle", z: 5, contactTest:ContactCategory, category: CircleCategory) //Sets physicsBody properties
   return spr
}()

func createCircle(of radius:CGFloat,color:UIColor) -> SKSpriteNode
{
   let spr = circle.copy()
   let scale = radius/1000.0
   spr.xScale = scale
   spr.yScale = scale
   spr.color = color
   spr.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
   return spr

}

func addCircle() {

    let attributes = getTargetAttributes() //sets size, position, and color of the circle
    let spr = createCircle(of:attribute.width,color:attributes.color)
    spr.position = attributes.position
    addChild(str)
}
```

Comment: In full disclosure, I haven't tried this exact solution but, out of simplicity for the code I already have, I tried 1) using xScale and yScale with the same SKShapeNode (i.e., not creating many SKShapeNodes) and 2) using SKSpriteNodes instead of SKShapeNodes, but replacing the texture image (i.e., color) each time.  Not creating multiple nodes did help but CPU usage is still 30-50% (maybe a 10% improvement).  In fact, the CPU usage is pretty high immediately after the scene is set up but before anything starts moving or getting added in real time.  Are there any other obvious areas to look at?

Comment: Also, I'm showing 60 FPS in the SKView when I add `showsFPS = true` but 120 FPS in the Debug navigator.  Could there be any issues there?  And one last detail, when I open the app and go to its initial view controller, the CPU usage will sit at 0% if I'm not doing anything.  When I segue to the GameViewController, it then spikes, but if I then return to the initial view controller, CPU usage does not return to 0% but sits at about 12-15%.  What might this indicate?

Comment: no,  not sure why you are seeing 120FPS only the newest iPad supports that I thought

Comment: Wow, you're quick on the reply.  I just added another detail to that previous comment.

Comment: The weird thing is that every other view controller runs at 60 FPS.  GameViewController is the one exception.